# loop ansible tasks for passing different vault secrets

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Hi I am running python script using ansible and sending email with attachment. where I am passing arguments as secret using ansible vault.

here is my playbook

```
- name: Run python script for generating Projects report
  command: python GetProjects.py -o { org1 } -p { pat1 }
  register: result
- debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"

- name: Run python script for generating Repos report
  command: python GetRepos.py -o { org1 } -p { pat1 }
  register: result
- debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"

- name: Sending an e-mail using the remote machine, not the Ansible controller node
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    from:
    to:
    subject: Reports
    body: Hi
    attach:
    -  {org1}_file1.csv
    -  {org1}_file2.scv
```

Once execution completed for org1 and pat1 and email sent with org1 files ,I want to run this script again for org2 and pat2 and generate files as {org2}_file1.csv , {org2_file2.csv} and send separate email.

How can I loop passing this arguments and sending separate email again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this, you could use `with_items` on each task but this is not so reusable.

Create `generateReport.yml` with two variables `organization` and `pat`, with those variables the playbook generates a file to attach with name `[organization]_file.csv` and sends the mail. Then create a playbook that includes the tasks of `generateReport.yml` sending the values of `organization` and `pat`.

`generateReport.yml`

```yaml
- name: Run python script for generating Projects report
  command: python GetProjects.py -o {{ organization }} -p {{ pat }}
  register: result

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

- name: Sending an e-mail using the remote machine, not the Ansible controller node
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    from: example@gmail.com
    to: emusk@gmail.com
    subject: Reports
    body: Hi
    attach:
    -  "{{ organization }}_file.csv"
```

`main.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Generate report
    include_tasks: generateReport.yml
    vars:
      organization: "{{ item.organization }}"
      pat: "{{ item.pat }}"
    with_items:
      - { organization: "org1", pat: "pat1" }
      - { organization: "org2", pat: "pat2" }
```

Comment: I am running your scripts as it is , this gives me error - fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'organization' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in generateReport.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Run python script for generating Projects report\n ^ here\n"}

Comment: my mistake, I forgot add vars, i just edited it. I hope it'll be useful.